# Extracting integers without decimals

Tags: java, regex

I need help with Regex to extract numbers from a string that is missing decimals.

```
Input
2 4.0 6.0 7 8 4.60

Output
2 7 8
```

**Edit:** Another follow up question to this regarding Regex and Java. Lets say that I want to add stuff to what I found (what I really want is taking 2 4.0 7.5 and turn it into 2.0 4.0 7.5, meaning adding missing .0 to the ones without a decimal), how would I do that and still keep the same untouched things of my String?

Comment: Instead of Regex, do a `String.Split(" ")` in your language of choice.  Exclude those elements in the resulting array containing a period.

Comment: … or do a split by the regex `/\s+(\d+\.\d*\s+)*/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For 2nd question: -**

Here's the solution for your 2nd requirement: -

```
String str = "2 4.0 6.0 7.5 8 4.60";
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=^|[ ])(\\d+)(?=$|[ ])", "$1.0");

System.out.println(str);  // Prints 2.0 4.0 6.0 7.5 8.0 4.60
```

---

**For 1st question : -**

You can use this Regex: -

```
(?<=^|[ ])(\\d+)(?=$|[ ])
```

This will match any sequence of `digits` followed and preceded by a `space`. Also, it matches digits at the end of the strings with the use of `^` and `$`.

Here's the implementation : -

```
    String str = "2 4.0 6.0 7 8 4.60";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|[ ])(\\d+)(?=[$ ])");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " ");
    }
```

**Output : -**

```
2 7 8
```

Comment: I think you will need to use `\s|^` respectively `\s|$` in the lookarounds to match first and last number

Comment: @m.buettner. Yeah, but if this is the reason for downvote, then it's clearly unfair. Still I'll add regex without `look-ahead` and `look-behind`.

Comment: @m.buettner. I tried with this: - `(?:^|\\s)(\\d+)(?:$|\\s)`. Can you get it to work?

Comment: @MagnusSjöstrand.. Added solution for your 2nd requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Going along with Robert Harveys comment, I would split it by spaces then iterate the results looking for a ".". It's easier to read and maintain rather than using a regex.

```
string[] splitStr = "2 4.0 6.0 7 8 4.60".split(' '); 
foreach(string s in splitStr){
   if(false == s.Contains("."))
       //do something
}
```

Comment: What if input is `2 4.0 hallo spots how are you today? 3 4.5 6` ?

Comment: @Omega: Not specified in the OP's requirements.  It's a cute username, by the way, but I don't see how anyone is going to be able to easily ping you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Right, not specified in the OP's question that input will contain **only** numbers...

Comment: @RobertHarvey agreed, it's not specified. If the input can truly be anything, you would just have to have a little more work in the IF statement. What I said in my post still stands, it's much easier to maintain to split and loop.

Comment: @Magnus Sjöstrand in that case you have a decision to make. Either resolution you choose will work, but it depends on the context of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My version:  `(?<![\.\d])\d+(?!\.\d+)`